# Is it possible to expose WCF service on a different port?

Tags: wcf, iis

Let's say I have an iis website with two https bindings. One for port 443 and the other one for port 553. The website hosts both ASP.NET MVC and WCF. This means that both of them are accessible via 553 and 443 ports. Is it possible to restrict WCF to be available on port 553 only? I tried the baseAddress config but it does not seem to work.

Env: iis 8.5, Windows 2012

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this does the trick. Note: it does not work with localhost.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <add prefix="https://fully_qualified_name:553"/>
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click your wcf application in iis then go to edit the bindings. Set the port here. If you have access to source click the wcf project in visual studio, there is a property for path, edit this. Any projects you have that use the web service will need their web reference updated. Change the port on here then right click and update reference